# Overriding Method with MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I'm creating a Java program that uses Swing to draw a face, and then I am using MouseListener to respond to mouse clicks to make one of the eyes blink. How would I make one of the eyes blink using MouseListener? The method paint(Graphics g) can only be created once with that name, so if I want to repeat it and edit it under the MouseListener code with one of the eyes turned into a line for blinking, how would I do that?

Here is my code so far:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Sans extends JPanel {

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    setSize(650, 650);
    g.drawOval(110, 250, 500, 275);
    g.setColor(new Color(226, 222, 217));
    g.fillOval(110, 250, 500, 275);

    g.drawOval(475, 300, 75, 75);
    g.setColor(new Color(74, 199, 226));
    g.fillOval(475, 300, 75, 75);

    g.drawOval(505, 330, 15, 15);
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    g.fillOval(505, 330, 15, 15);

    g.drawOval(175, 300, 75, 75);
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    g.fillOval(175, 300, 75, 75);

    g.drawOval(205, 330, 15, 15);
    g.setColor(new Color(232, 255, 243));
    g.fillOval(205, 330, 15, 15);

    g.drawOval(350, 375, 20, 50);
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    g.fillOval(350, 375, 20, 50);

    g.drawArc(290, 360, 150, 150, 180, 180);
    g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    g.fillArc(290, 360, 150, 150, 180, 180);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Font font = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 15);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Sans spook = new Sans();
    frame.add(spook);
    frame.setSize(750, 750);

    frame.setTitle("I'VE GOTTEN A TON OF WORK DONE TODAY. A SKELE-TON.");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public class BlinkHandler implements MouseListener {



    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }


    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Give `paint` access to a state variable that says whether or not to blink. Then have the mouse listener alter the state, and have `paint` read it.

Comment: Overriding `paint` and calling `super.paintComponent` is a really, really bad idea.  Override the `paintComponent` instead (and call it's super)

Comment: Your `MouseListener` will need some kind of reference back to what ever is going to control the blinking. I personally prefer a controller or model and make use of an observer pattern to generate the required events, but that might be taking you a little further beyond you capabilities right now

Comment: Is there an example of this paint access to state variable, and then altering the state? Sorry, but I am not exactly sure what you mean by that.